# vuetify trying to display object's value with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm building a function in vuejs where the user select some tables in a database and the tables' columns names should automatically appear in a v-list-item component.
The problem is I'm not being able to print those names in a good way.

This is the code I'm using:

```js
<v-list-item v-for="(item,index) in this.columns" :key="index">
  <v-list-item v-for="ved in item" :key="ved.id">
    <v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-title >{{ved}}</v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
  </v-list-item>
</v-list-item>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        columns:{},
      };
    },
  }
</script>
```

to make the code look cleaner i didn't include the methods and the other variables.

for example if i choose 2 tables in the db and one of them has only 1 column and the other one has 3 columns, the result i get from this code is:

> id   //column of the first table

> name, last_name,email   // columns of the second table

But i want the columns of the second table to be printed separately, not in the same line divided by a comma.
what i want is(without the numbers):

1. id //first column
2. name //second column
3. last_name
4. email

This is what i get from the axios request:

> [
> [
> "id"
> ],
> [
> "name",
> "last_name",
> "email"
> ]
> ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply treat the **two arrays as a list** and the **items inside them as a list-item**

```
<v-list v-for="(item, index) in columns" :key="index">
    <v-list-item v-for="ved in item" :key="ved.id">
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title>{{ ved }}</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```